# Understanding linker errors

Tags: c++, virtual

I wrote the following program with virtual functions:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    A(){ init(); }
    void init(){ foo(); }
};

struct B : A
{
    virtual void foo(){ }
};

B a;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a75c44b81a39f042)

I thought some linker-error should be ccured becuase there's no implementation of the `foo` was found. We got runtime error instead. Why? Why not the linker error?

Comment: Missing functions do not require a linker error. It is undefined behaviour with no diagnostic required.  It is just quality of implementation whether the linker actually pipes up or not.

Comment: Maybe it's just compiler strategy not to walk through all inheritance relationships to check pure virtual function implementation.

Comment: It is not an error to leave a pure virtual function undefined. It is a runtime error to call one.

Comment: In general case, it is not possible to check the targets of all dynamic (i.e. run-time dispatched) calls in the program at compile time. Which is why in general case it is not possible to determine whether a given pure virtual function is called or not.  For this reason, it is not possible to diagnose such errors at compile time.

Comment: @MattMcNabb while it's true that the standard allows to omit diagnostics (I've missed it on the first reading), no known implementation does so.

Comment: @n.m.: Not sure what you mean. The OP's code is one example of what is perfectly sufficient to fool a typical implementation. Note, BTW, that it does not matter whether there's a body provided for a pure virtual function. A virtual call to such function still leads to undefined behavior. The above code will still crash at run-time, even if you provide a body for `A::foo()`.

Comment: @AnT As far as I know the providing body for virtual functions is for code reuses sakes only, isn't?

Comment: @AnT which one of my statements is unclear?

Comment: @n.m. the code in this question is a counterexample, the implementation could give a diagnostic but doesn't

Comment: @n.m.: I thought your previous implied that every known implementation is capable of detecting calls to pure virtual functions at compile time and issuing diagnostics for such calls.

Comment: @AnT I have no idea why anyone would think that. A program must define all functions that are odr-used. No diagnostic is required for this but all known implementations issue one. The pure virtual function is not odr-used here so this rule is irrelevant. Of course no implementation can detect all calls to p.v.f. at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you have to understand here is that a call to `foo()` made while the constructor of class `A` is active is dispatched to `A::foo()`, even if the full object under construction has type `B` and `B` overrides `foo()`. The presence of `B::foo()` is simply ignored.

This means that your code attempts to call `A::foo()`. Since `A::foo()` is a pure virtual function, the behavior of your code is undefined.

C++ language make no guarantees of what kind of "error" should occur in such cases. Which means that your expectations of "linker error" are completely unfounded. If a programs makes an attempt to perform a virtual call to a pure virtual function the behavior is simply *undefined*. That is the only thing that can be said here from the C++ language point of view.

How this undefined behavior will manifest itself in practical implementations depends on the implementation. Undefined behavior is allowed to manifest itself through compile-time errors, for example.

In your case, your program attempts to make a virtual call to pure virtual function `A::foo()`. In general case the compiler dispatches virtual calls *dynamically*, through a run-time mechanism that implements polymorphism (so called *virtual method table* is the most popular one). In some cases, when compiler can determine the exact type of the object used in the call, it optimizes the code and makes an ordinary direct (non-dynamic) call to a virtual function.

In practice, if a function pure virtual, its virtual method table entry contains a null pointer. A dynamic call to such function typically leads to run-time error. Meanwhile, a direct (optimized) call to such function typically leads to a compiler or linker error.

In your example the compiler did not optimize the call. It made a full-fledged dynamic call to `A::foo()` through the virtual method table. The null pointer in that table triggered the run-time error.

If you call your pure virtual function directly from the constructor

```
 A() { foo(); }
```

a typical compiler will normally make a direct (optimized) call to `foo()`, which will typically lead to a linker error.

Comment: You mean the behavior is undefined if we call to a function from the constructor that is pure virtual in the constructor's class. We have no guarantee about producing warnings or something else. Is that why Scott Meyers suggest we don't call virtual function in cinstructors?

Comment: @Dmitry Bundin: The reason books suggest not to call virtual functions in constructors (or destructors) is what I stated above: when constructor (destructor) is active, the virtual dispatch mechanism works in the "truncated" version of the hierarchy: from the root to the class under construction. Everything below in the hierarchy is ignored as if it does not exist. Such "truncated" polymorphism can be useful, if one knows what one's doing. So, I would not be as aggressive as Scott Meyers is.

Comment: But for many newcomers to the language this "truncated" behavior is quite surprising, which is why it is often recommended to avoid virtual calls in constructors (and destructors). But again, once you understand how it works and know what you are doing, there's nothing wrong with using it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

`B` does have an implementation of `foo` so there's no problem for the linker.

As far as I know, the fact that `A` is calling `foo` at a bad time is something the compiler/linker isn't required to figure out. (And although it might be simple to do such a check in this case, I'm sure we could come up with much more complicated cases that would be harder or perhaps impossible to catch.)

Comment: There's certainly a linker error when removing the curly braces defining the body of the empty function `foo` in the B struct: [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea6f0128e7b2c7e3)

Comment: The OP's code above calls `A::foo`, not `B::foo`. Which is why it is irrelevant that `B::foo` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is result of calling virtual functions from within constructors. The function called is the function in A, not more derived functions. C++ standard, section 12.7.4 states,

> Member functions, including virtual functions (10.3), can be called
>   during construction or destruction (12.6.2). **When a virtual function
>   is called directly or indirectly from a constructor or from a
>   destructor, including during the construction or destruction of the
>   classes non-static data members, and the object to which the call
>   applies is the object (call it x) under construction or destruction,
>   the function called is the final overrider in the constructor's or
>   destructor's class and not one overriding it in a more-derived class.**
>   If the virtual function call uses an explicit class member access
>   (5.2.5) and the object expression refers to the complete object of x
>   or one of that object's base class subobjects but not x or one of its
>   base class subobjects, the behavior is undefined.

Now, you are cheating in your example. You are calling a normal function from your constructor and then a virtual function from your normal function. Change your code to,

```
struct A
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    A(){ foo(); }
};
```

and you'll get your error,

```
warning: pure virtual ‘virtual void A::foo()’ called from constructor [enabled by default]
_ZN1AC2Ev[_ZN1AC5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `A::foo()'
```